# Error al conectar WebSocket php - javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5, websocket

Estoy practicando `webSocket` y trato de hacer conexión `php` con `javascript - html5` para poder posterior hacer un chat, asi que tengo lo siguiente en el `servidor.php`.

```
$host="127.0.0.1";
$port="3333";
$socket= socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
socket_bind($socket,$host,$port) or die("error al vincular socket en el cliente");
echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
socket_listen($socket);
$i=0;
while(true){
    $client[$i++]=socket_accept($socket);
    $menssage=socket_read($client[$i], 1024);
    echo $menssage;
    $menssage="Hola".$menssage."\n";

    socket_write($client[$i], $menssage."\n\r",1024);
    socket_close($client[$i]);
}
socket_close($socket);
```

Y realizo una petición desde mi cliente de la siguiente manera:

```
    $("#conectar").click(function(){
        token=document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
        conectar(token)
    });
    function conectar(tokenuser){
        loadDoc("ws://127.0.0.1:3333",tokenuser, myFunction);
    }
    function loadDoc(url,clave ,cFunction) {
        if ("WebSocket" in window) {
            var ws = new WebSocket(url);
            ws.onopen = function (clave) {
                ws.send(clave);
            };
            ws.onerror = function (error) {
                console.log('WebSocket Error');
            };
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                cFunction(evt.data);
            };
            ws.onclose = function () {
                console.log("el WS fue cerrado");
            };
        }else{
            console.log("descargue chrome");
        }
    }
    function myFunction(resultado) {
        console.log(resultado);
    }
```

Una vez codificado todo ejecuto el servicio:

```
C:\Users\minombre>php -f C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php
La operacin se complet correctamente.
```

Y todo bien hasta ahi,pero una vez que presiono **Conectar** me arroja un error al lado del servidor:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 12
>   PHP Warning:  socket_read() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 12
>
> Warning: socket_read() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 12
>   PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 16
>   PHP Warning:  socket_write() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 16
>
> Warning: socket_write() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 16
>   PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 17
>   PHP Warning:  socket_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 17
>
> Warning: socket_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webSocket\servidor.php on line 17

No se que hice mal, si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin probarlo, diría que tu problema está aquí:

```
$i = 0;
$client[$i++] = ...
```

Ahí empiezas con `$i === 0`, y luego lo **incrementas**, con lo que `$i` pasa a valer `1`. Luego, cuando haces

```
socket_write( $client[$i], ...
socket_close( $client[$i] );
```

En realidad estás accediendo con `$i === 1`, que no lo tienes definido dentro del *array*.

La solución mas sencilla: incrementa `$i` **al final** del bucle:

```
while( true ) {
  $client[$i] = socket_accept( $socket );
//          ^-- CAMBIA ESTO
  $menssage = socket_read( $client[$i], 1024 );
  echo $menssage;
  $menssage = "Hola" . $menssage . "\n";

  socket_write( $client[$i], $menssage . "\n\r", 1024 );
  socket_close( $client[$i] );
  ++$i; // <-- AQUÍ
}
```

Comment: Pues si, ese es mi error, pero ahora tengo otro error que no se porque pasa, ya que en `echo $menssage` me aparece::GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:33333
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.9
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 96JVLO8dlyCUGArTpVnEbw==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflat

Comment: y en mi cliente: WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:33333/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Comment: Muy sencillo: un WebSocket **no es** un socket *raw*, como tu lo estás haciendo. Empieza con una petición HTTP normal desde el cliente, con la cabecera `Upgrade` indicando que quiere ser actualizada a `WebSocket`. Hay varias versiones del protocolo, implicando que el servidor ha de responder de una forma u otra. Y los datos van codificados de una forma concreta, nada de texto *tal cual* como tu lo estás haciendo. Puedes empezar [por la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) para ir preparándote :-)

Comment: Y ya que estamos: PHP no es el mejor lenguaje para WebSockets. PHP inicia un proceso por cada petición, por lo que consume muchos recursos del servidor. Y suele tener un tiempo de vida máximo para cada proceso, lo cual limita el tiempo que tu WebSocket permanecerá abierto. Aunque, para hacer pruebas locales e ir *destripando* el protocolo, no tiene importancia :-)